# Save QGIS point layer as KML and retain attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, kml, fields-attributes

***QGIS 2.18.5***

I've done this in the past but I can't remember how I did it! I'm saving a point layer as a kml and trying to bring over the attribute data across with the kml. I've got some screenshots of the result from the past:

[image]
[image]

I've read a [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136604/qgis-exporting-attributes-in-a-kml-file) about exporting 2 attributes but obviously I managed to export a selection of my attributes. I'm not an experienced coder and there weren't any intricate expressions involved. I remember filling in the 'Description Field' and 'NameField' shown below but from recollection, that only changed what the pins in Google Earth are titled with - shown as parcel numbers in my case.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe I missed this....when saving the vector layer as a .kml, there is a inconspicuous drop down arrow which says "select fields to export and their export options". Problem solved!

Comment: Interesting... and well hidden. It also allow using the name/description fields! In Google Earth though, it seems to display either the description or the data table but not both

Answer (score 1):

The output you got is from the OGR tool:

```
Processing menu -> Toolbox -> GDAL/OGR -> Conversion -> convert format
```

Trying it with a polygon layer, the output KML displayed in Google Earth shows no name and empty description, but clicking on an item brings the attribute table.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to do this once and got point attribute data into a set of pins in google earth. Now when I try to convert any other shapefile the process completes and the dialogue box auto-closes - but there is no kml saving to my destination. No error either.

Comment: Make sure the KML file extension is also selected, as it defaults to shapefiles (even if you have selected the kml format). Otherwise try the [command line](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) version as you control all parameters

Comment: Afraid that doesn't seem to fix the issue. The command line version seems very daunting to me. Is that something you plug into python?

Comment: I can't believe I missed this....when saving the vector layer as a .kml, there is a inconspicuous drop down arrow which says "select fields to export and their export options". Problem solved!

Comment: You could just run it in windows command prompt:  `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\ogr2ogr.exe" -f KML "C:/output.kml" "C:/source.shp" layername`