# QGIS 3.10 attribute table change to default or modify when export the layer to different format

Tags: qgis, geojson, attribute-table, kml, google-earth

When I export my newly digitalized layer I noticed, that my data attribute changes.
In the QGIS I set the data attribute table like this:

[image]

but each single export to the different format change it, as it appear as a new separate layer in QGIS.

For instance, when I exported my file as a .kml layer, then my data attribute table looks like this:

[image]

My digitalized layer with set attribute layer is already active (1), all other are exports to the different formats, where this data attribute table have changed (2)

[image]

For example in Google Earth it looks like this:

[image]

Is it something, which I should do between these steps?

Comment: Exporting to kml adds a bunch of columns.

Comment: Have a look at this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136604/qgis-exporting-attributes-in-a-kml-file it may help you. Also why the geojson tag ?

Answer (score 1):

OK,
According to this query proposed by @J.R:

[QGIS exporting attributes in a KML file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136604/qgis-exporting-attributes-in-a-kml-file)

which refers mainly to the older versions of QGIS (2x)

In QGIS 3.10 we must change in the "Geometry" type from automatic to Polygon as per in the image below:

[image]

And then we will have our data attribute table shown in Google Earth as follows:

[image]